# PDO lastInsertID Fatal Error

Tags: pdo

I have class named DB.
When i insert something in table, it does but returning an error message:

> Call to a member function lastInsertId() on null in /home/...

Everything is OK but why this problem occurs i don't have any idea.
My codes:

```
class DB
{
   public static $pdo = NULL;
   public static $last_stmt = NULL;

public static function instance()
{
    return ($pdo == NULL ? self::init() : $pdo);
}

public static function init()
{
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=" . MYSQL_HOST . ";dbname=" . MYSQL_DB, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASS);
    $pdo->exec("SET NAMES utf8");
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    return $pdo;
}

public static function query($query, $bindings = NULL)
{
    if( is_null($bindings) ) 
    {
        if( !($last_stmt = self::instance()->query($query)) ) 
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        $last_stmt = self::prepare($query);
        if( !$last_stmt->execute($bindings) ) 
        {
            return false;
        }

    }

    return $last_stmt;
}

public static function insert($query, $bindings = NULL)
{
    if( !($stmt = self::query($query, $bindings)) ) 
    {
        return false;
    }

    return $pdo->lastInsertId();
}
```

}

Comment: Turn up error reporting in your code, always when developing and testing. `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and you should see PHP issue a notice about an undefined variable `$pdo` in the `insert()` method call.  The variable `$pdo` is not known in that scope, and you probably meant to call it via the singleton `self::instance()->lastInsertId()`